# Subgroups and factor groups of finite abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I have tried to prove two statements that I came up with, and would appreciate if someone checked my proofs. If the statements are wrong, please give an counterexample. If they are right, please try to give me an easier proof.

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. I will presume we know the following: $G$ can be expressed as a direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$ groups, where $p$ is a prime number. This expression of $G$ as a direct product of these groups is the same up to an isomorphism.

**1** Let $N$ be a subgroup of $G=\mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{k_1}} \oplus ..\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{k_n}}$, with all $k_i>0$ for $i=1,..,n$. Then $N \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{l_1}} \oplus ..\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{l_n}}$, for some $l_i$, $i=1,..,n$, where $l_i \leq k_i$ for all $i=1,..,n$.

*proof:*
We know that $N$ can be expressed as $\mathbb{Z}_{{q_1}^{j_1}} \oplus ..\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{{q_m}^{j_m}}$, where $q_i, i=1,..,m$ are prime numbers. We also know,  that the order of any element $g \in G$ divides the order $G$. If any of the $q_i$ are not contained in the expression describing $G$, we get an contradiction, because $G$ does not contain an element of order $q_i$.

Pick a $q$ from the expression of $N$, and consider all the $i$ and $u$ such that $q_i=q=p_u$, and ${k_u} \geq 1$ ($k_u$ being the coefficient from ${p_u}^{k_u}$),  and ${j_i} \geq 1$, . There can not be fewer $u$, because if there were, $N$ would have more elements of order $q$. We can apply the same argument to the case of $u$ and $i$ such that ${k_u-1} \geq 1$,  and ${j_i-1} \geq 1$ -if there were fewer $u$ than $i$, we would have that $N$ contains more elements of order $q^2$ . $q$ was picked arbitrarily, and therefore we get the wanted statement of $N \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{l_1}} \oplus ..\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{l_n}}$, for some $l_i$, $i=1,..,n$, where $l_i \leq k_i$ for all $i=1,..,n$.

**2** Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{k_1}} \oplus ..\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{k_n}}$, and $N=p^{l_1}\mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{k_1}} \oplus ..\oplus p^{l_n}\mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{k_n}}$, with $l_i \leq k_i$ and $k_i>0$ for all $i=1,..,n$. Then $\frac{G}{N} \simeq \frac{G_1}{N_1} \oplus ..  \oplus \frac{G_n}{N_n}$,  where $G_i$ is the respective projection of $G$, and $N_i$ is the respective projection of $N_i$. Also, $\frac{G}{N} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{l_1}} \oplus ..  \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{l_n}}$

*proof*: The subgroups $M_i= \left \langle e_i + N \right \rangle $ together generate $\frac{G}{N}$, and the interesection of any of them with the others is $N$, so $M_i$ give us an internal direct sum of $\frac{G}{N}$. Each one of them is also isomorphic to the respective group $\frac{G_i}{N_i}$, giving us the wanted result.

**3** Let $N$ be a subgroup of $G=\mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{k_1}} \oplus ..\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{k_n}}$. Then we can express $\frac{G}{N}$ the following way: $\frac{G}{N} \simeq \frac{G_1}{H_1} \oplus ..  \oplus \frac{G_n}{H_n}$, where $G_i$ is the respective $\mathbb{Z}_{{p_i}^{k_i}}$ group, and $H_i$ is some subgroup of $G_i$.

I don't know whether this is true, or how to go about the proof. I've tried injecting $N$ into $G$ by using the expression from **1** (by that I mean that the expression of $N$ in **1** gives me a relatively clear way of injecting $N$ into $G$), making it possible to use **2**, but $A \simeq B$ for $A,B \leq C$ doesn't necessarily imply $\frac{C}{A} \simeq \frac{C}{B}$, so I'm not sure that will work, because I don't know whether $\frac{G}{N} \simeq \frac{G}{T}$ is true, for $T$ the injection of $N$.

Instead the approach might be something like this - we could show that $\frac{G}{N}$ is isomorphic to some subgroup $F$ of $G$. Using **1**, we know $F$ is isomorphic to some $\mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{l_1}} \oplus ..\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{l_n}}$, and so we define $H_i$, in such a way, so that $\frac{G_i}{H_i} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{{p_i}^{l_i}}$. We can do that by injecting $\mathbb{Z}_{{p_i}^{k_i - l_i}}$ into $G_i=\mathbb{Z}_{{p_i}^{k_i}}$ (there is only one injection like that) - if we then pick $H_i$ to be the image of that injection, $\frac{G_i}{H_i} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{{p_i}^{l_i}}$ should be true, giving us the wanted result.

Comment: 2 seems to be wrong. Yu can have $G\cong \Bbb Z_{16}\oplus\Bbb Z_8$ and $N\cong \Bbb Z_4\oplus \Bbb Z_2$ and yet $G/N$ might be $\Bbb Z_4\oplus \Bbb Z_4$ or $\Bbb Z_8\oplus\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: For 1, since G is finite and abelian, then N must be finite and abelian, so by the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, you're done.

Comment: @JazzyMatrix The theorem doesn't prove what the expression of $N$ is.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  I'm not sure what you mean. $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_8 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ so I presume you mean **2** somehow implies that to be true, giving a contradiction. But I don't see how that's true, $N$  is written explicitly as a specific type of subgroup of $G$. $N$ isn't just some group of type $N \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{l_1}} \oplus ..\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{l_n}}$ , it's exactly $N=p^{l_1}\mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{k_1}} \oplus ..\oplus p^{l_n}\mathbb{Z}_{{p_n}^{k_n}}$,  so we only get one expression for $\frac{G}{N}$ from **2**.